# How to solve the sql execution error in snowsql client?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am getting error while creating a table in snowsql client which says
003540 (42501): SQL execution error: Creating table on shared database 'SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA' is not allowed.
can anyone help me out how to resolve this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Snowflake sessions have "context", such as current role, warehouse, database, and schema.
It appears your current session "context" has your database set to one of sample databases,
which was created from a "Share".
Databases created from a share are readonly, so you cannot create a table in them.

The good news is the fix is easy, you can either:

1. use a fully qualified table name (databaseName.schemaName.tableName) to create your table in a database/schema that you have proper access to.

   `USE DATABASE snowflake_sample_data;`

   `USE SCHEMA tpch_sf1;`

   `CREATE TABLE myDatabase.mySchema.myNewTableName AS SELECT * FROM lineitem;`
2. change your session context to a database/schema you have access to create tables, and use the fully qualified table name of the tables you are reading from.

   `USE DATABASE myDatabase;`

   `USE SCHEMA mySchema;`

   `CREATE TABLE myNewTableName AS SELECT * FROM snowflake_sample_data.tpch_sf1.lineitem;`

Relevant docs links:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/use.html

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-sharing-intro.html#how-does-secure-data-sharing-work

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/name-resolution.html

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/sample-data-using.html#querying-tables-and-views-in-the-sample-database